# How to configure Glimpse to work with virtual directories?

Tags: iis, virtual-directory, glimpse

My application has a virtual directory that points to a shared folder of images on a remote file server. When trying to access the images via the browser (like `http://webserver/app/VD-alias/image.png`) I get a "configuration error":

```
An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to start monitoring changes to '\\fileserver\sharedfolder\web.config'.
```

After a lot of investigating I suspect this is a security issue. However:

- The AppPool uses `Integrated` pipeline identity is `NETWORK SERVICE`.
- The file server only allows user domain access not machine account access (which is what the web server would use for this AppPool identity).
- But in IIS, the virtual directory is configured to use specific domain account credentials to access the shared folder, so everything should be fine regarding access.

After a lot of investigation I realized that this had to do with the Glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy being On. When I turn it off, everything works fine. At the moment this is my Glimpse settings in web.config:

```
  <glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
    <runtimePolicies>
      <ignoredTypes>
        <add type="Glimpse.AspNet.Policy.LocalPolicy, Glimpse.AspNet" />
      </ignoredTypes>
    </runtimePolicies>
  </glimpse>
```

So I'm wondering if Glimpse is not using the virtual directory credentials set by IIS? Or what else could Glimpse be doing differently that would prevent access to the images?

In any case, I was wondering if there was a way to prevent glimpse from interfering with that specific path or with images in general?
I've tried using:

```
      <uris>
        <add regex=".*uploads.*" />
      </uris>
```

and

```
      <uris>
        <add regex=".*/.*\.png" />
      </uris>
```

and

```
      <contentTypes>
        <add contentType="image/png" />
      </contentTypes>
```

I've also tried changing the `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests`. I've tried different IIS versions and the latest Glimpse version.

But none of them seem to make any difference except when I turn off Glimpse.
Has anyone faced this issue? I'm pretty sure it's reproduceable. How can I get Glimpse and my virtual directory to play nice?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've not had any issues getting Glimpse to work with virtual directories as you've described. Do you have any other pertinent configuration?

Comment: @nikmd23 Nothing that I can think of at the moment. For the virtual directory, the IIS Authentication is Anonymous authentication but the anonymous user identity is set to the domain user (right click Anonymous Authentication and click edit and select specific user) who is also the account used for the "Physical Path Credentials" under the Virtual Directory settings. That's the only thing I can think of that's remotely unusual. Everything else is pretty regular. Are you not getting the same results with the same configuration?